# Would repeated non-interfering kerchunking with ID within ten minutes be illegal or just annoying?

Tags: united-states, legal, repeater

I'm not going to do this. I'm just curious whether it's legal or not.

Suppose there's a net at 8:00 on a repeater. There is no traffic prior to the net. Is it legal to repeatedly kerchunk the repeater starting at 7:55, stopping at 7:59, then checking into the net with ID at 8:03, transmitting the call sign but never identifying as the kerchunker?

Comment: not a native speaker. What's kerchunking?

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's the sound an FM receiver makes when the signal drops. You can make this sound on a ham repeater by quickly tapping and releasing the push to talk button.

Comment: (presumably any FM repeater will do it, but I'm only familiar with ham repeaters)

Comment: Simplex FM does it too, but you don't hear your own kerchunks on simplex, only other people do. On a repeater, you still don't hear your own repeated kerchunk, but the repeater makes another one when dropping its carrier; that's the one you hear.

Comment: The word is definitely radio jargon; I would guess at least 80% of native speakers don't know it.

Comment: Ah so it's just noise getting erroneously demodulated by the FM receiver before the squelch closes. So, kerchunking is just the transmission of a short segment of unmodulated carrier with the goal of opening someone else's squelch just enough to make the receiver make noise. But: why would someone do that?

Comment: @MarcusMüller there are two reasons: doing it once to test if you're in range of a repeater or if it is functioning (legal if you ID afterwards), or being annoying (the subject of this question).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it illegal to key up and not identify?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1845/is-it-illegal-to-key-up-and-not-identify)

Comment: @Rob no, because there is identification after the keying.

Comment: @Someone, you can't come back a few minutes later with an ID and claim that is an ID **during** your previous transmission, and the answer covers that case: https://ham.stackexchange.com/a/1851/14679

Comment: @Rob you don't have to identify each transmission. It sounds like kerchunking then identifying after other people talk, without making it clear that you're identifying the kerchunk, but in a conversation, you can just have a normal conversation and identify every ten minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you find an interesting [loophole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loophole)? The idea being roughly: "so long as I transmit my callsign within 10 minutes of an annoying transmission, it's legal".

There's at least three restrictions I see against an example like the one you give. I don't think there's really any loophole here.

---

The biggest obstacle I see is in the identification requirements themselves. The rules don't simply say "transmit your callsign" but rather:

> Each amateur station, except a space station or telecommand station, must transmit its assigned call sign on its transmitting channel at the end of each communication, and at least every 10 minutes during a communication, **for the purpose of clearly making the source of the transmissions from the station known** to those receiving the transmissions. No station may transmit unidentified communications or signals, or transmit as the station call sign, any call sign not authorized to the station.

— [47 CFR 97.119(a)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-47/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-97#p-97.119(a)), emphasis added.

In short, your thought experiment fails this requirement. You have transmitted your callsign, yes, but it was **not** for the purpose of clearly making known the source of your (earlier, malicious) transmissions.

---

The other prevention against this, a little more of a grey area perhaps, is whether your initial ["kerchunking"](https://newhams.info/2016/10/07/kerchunking/) was a legal transmission to begin with.

The closest on the list of authorized uses of the amateur airwaves might be:

> Brief transmissions **necessary** to make adjustments to the station;

— [47 CFR 97.111(b)(1)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-47/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-97#p-97.111(b)(1)), emphasis again added.

Whereas

> false or deceptive messages, signals or identification

are prohibited by [47 CFR 97.113(a)(4)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-47/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-97#p-97.113(a)(4))

It could be argued that your kerchunking was *unnecessary* and/or that your later identification as an "innocent check-in" to the net while not false was *deceptive*. Thus neither your kerchunk **nor** your check-in were necessarily legal to transmit in the first place.

To be clear, while it would still be impolite I think it *would* be legal — if truly testing access to a repeater! — to kerchunk a few times and then fess up with your callsign shortly thereafter. But your example is neither: the initial unidentified transmissions were not for an authorized **purpose**, nor does the later callsign transmission **identify** the earlier transmissions.

Underlying this is the fairly unambiguous rule that

> No amateur operator shall willfully or maliciously interfere with or cause interference to any radio communication or signal.

— [47 CFR 97.101(d)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-47/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-97#p-97.101(d))

And yes, even though the repeater may not have been in use I suspect deliberate repetitive kerchunking would still count as:

> Harmful interference.  Interference which endangers the functioning of a radionavigation service or of other safety services or **seriously degrades, obstructs or repeatedly interrupts** a radiocommunication service operating in accordance with the Radio Regulations.

[47 CFR 97.3(a)(23)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-47/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-97#p-97.3(a)(23)), emphasis added

---

Finally, while the recourse isn't 100% clear, it looks to be within the rights of a repeater operator to categorically ban usage by any/all kerchunking stations:

> Limiting the use of a repeater to only certain user stations is permissible.

— [47 CFR 97.205(e)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-47/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-97#p-97.205(e))

Answer (score 2):

It's illegal.

> § 97.119 Station identification. (a) ... No station may transmit
> unidentified communications or signals, or transmit as the station
> call sign, any call sign not authorized to the station.

I think it's also annoying, but that's an opinion.

Answer (score 2):

While transmitting without identifying is illegal, and intentionally "kerchunking" a repeater is probably illegal (certainly, if you don't identify), not all kerchunking is illegal.

This could also happen accidentally if you are close enough to the repeater to trigger it to open squelch, but not close enough for your audio (and identification) to get through.

It's still annoying, and if you realize this is the issue, it's also frustrating for a different reason, and likely to both the transmitter and the listener.